# Wordpress: 301 Redirect from one subfolder to another with the same name

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have just set-up a wordpress multi-site network on an installation with one already active blog.
It worked well, but my permalinks are, predictably, messed up some.
The original url was like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog/category/this-is-my-post/
```

After the multi-site installation it is now:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog/blog/category/this-is-my-post/
```

I have already tried quite a few htaccess-commands only to have them not work or run into an infinite loop, because it repeats the /blog/ part ad nauseum.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: I don't see how that would get rid of the infinite loop. Just in case I overlooked something elemental, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !blog/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [QSA]
```